# Subtracting seconds from int with no formatting

Tags: python

I have an array of different times that looks like this:

```
20120628061533.0, 20120628064851.0, 20120628064853.0, 20120628064920.0, 20120628064929.0
```

what I want to do is subtract 10 seconds 30 seconds and one minute from the times but the problem I am facing is that I can't simply just subtract 10 or 30 or 60 because then the numbers would no longer be in time format(ie. the last two digits can be greater than 60)

Is there anyway to do this easily?

Comment: There are much better ways to do time and date math, especially in a language like python.  This is a particularly tricky and nuanced wheel to try and reinvent, you would be much better off rethinking your approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html):

```
import datetime

a = 20120628061533.0

dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(int(a)), '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
dt -= datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)

print dt.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
```

prints

```
20120628061433
```

Anyway, keep the `datetime` objects and convert them to strings only when writing to screen/file.

Comment: Way too fast; hadn't finished typing yet! +1 from me.

Comment: You can use the `%f` modifier to capture the microseconds portion as well if that is important.

Comment: @MattH - the decimal point and the zero may be tricky to parse…

Comment: @eumiro: that's a good point. I hope I'd have spotted it once I had a functioning solution with the available sample data, but I aborted once I saw yours appear.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no easy way to do that in general. If you're writing in an object-oriented language, I would recommend creating a class that can be constructed from an integer such as the ones you showed and that represents the corresponding date and time internally as a bunch of integers, one for year, one for month, etc. You could then handle the "conversion factors" among these date/time elements (e.g. 60 seconds in a minute, 60 minutes in an hour, etc., making sure to be careful with number of days in a month) as you are doing the arithmetic.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that this was tagged with Python. I don't know much about Python so maybe someone else can provide details.

Comment: I don't mean to be smug, but if you don't think there is an easy way to do that in an object-oriented language, maybe you should consider other languages?